# State-space model of a buck converter in DCM

Tags: buck, boost, buck-boost, state-space

I have a problem getting the state-space representation of a buck converter in DCM.

[image: Buck-Converter]

There are two switch cycles between one period.

If the switch is closed the circuit looks like this:

[image: Switch-Closed]

After applying KVL you get for the state variables:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\mathrm di_L}{\mathrm dt} &= \dfrac{1}{L}\cdot(U_{in}-u_C)\\
\dfrac{\mathrm du_C}{\mathrm dt} &= \dfrac{1}{C}\cdot(i_{L}-i_{R})
\end{align}

The same procedure can be followed when the switch is open:

[image: Switch-Open]

So the state variables are:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\mathrm di_L}{\mathrm dt} &= -\dfrac{u_C}{L}\\
\dfrac{\mathrm du_C}{\mathrm dt} &= \dfrac{1}{C}\cdot(i_{L}-i_{R})
\end{align}

So, there is a procedure for extracting the state variables.

I would like to know how to get:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{di_L}{dt}=~...\\
\dfrac{du_C}{dt}=~...
\end{align}

when the buck converter is working in DCM.

In *[State-space average Modeling of DC-DC Converters with parasitic in Discontinuous Conduction Mode (DCM)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/53187372.pdf)* on page 20-21 the authors describe how they got to a solution, but I don't understand their method (or the way they describe it).

Comment: I don't know much about state space models, but your equation for \$\frac{di_L}{dt}\$ with the switch open is only valid for the first part of the time the switch is open. Once \$i_L\$ drops to zero (because this is DCM), you need a another equation.

Comment: yes sure, the state-space model is only valid for CCM

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if this for homework but I would not recommend to use the state-space averaging (SSA) technique to model a CCM or DCM converter whether this is a buck or buck-boost. The SSA is quite complex and requires matrix manipulations with the need to build a small-signal model at the end. The PWM switch model is the modern way to go. Associated with the fast analytical circuit techniques, it is unbeatable in speed and ease of analysis. Furthermore, SSA fails to predict that the DCM buck is still a heavily damped second-order converter what the PWM switch did.

Comment: You can have a look here to learn about the PWM switch model: https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf

Comment: Thanks, but this is no homework. Im working for my thesis to develop a Model of an Cascaded-Buck-Boost for Control. I wanted to implement an state-regulator. I have done a LOT of Matrix Manipulations, and everything is OK! But i want to add the DCM-Mode. But i will have a look to the doc, thank you!

Comment: I see, in this case please have a look at this document https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/80b8/76a388ca3f18c9c5922bb566bcaa9bd5f935.pdf where authors have identified why the original SSA failed to predict the second pole in DCM.

Comment: So its not easy to Control the SSA Model in DCM? What are the consequences working with the model with the missing pole?

Comment: For a long time, the second pole has been ignored but if you push crossover really high in DCM, not having the second pole fails to predict the correct phase margin once the loop is closed. SSA not only fails to predict the second pole but also the presence of a RHP zero in the DCM buck-boost and boost converters. So really, the PWM switch is the way to go at least for these converters.

Comment: What do you mean by pushing the crossover high in DCM? The switch-frequency is 48kHz.

Comment: @VerbalKint so i have to develop the PWM-Switch Model of the Converter to calculate the Controller for DCM-Mode, but CCM-Controller works for SSA-Model?

Comment: Yes, the SSA prediction is correct in CCM and you can reuse your equations. But if you look at how to derive the transfer function in CCM with the PWM switch model, you will not want to go back to SSA! Good luck.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good! But very sad hearing that after spending weeks to extract the small-signal-transfer Function  and linearize the cascaded-Buck-Boost with parasitic parts. 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100478/discussion-between-adaptive-and-verbal-kint).

Answer (score 1):

There are **three** states each cycle:

1. Switch closed, your first equation applies (less the transistor drop).
2. Switch open, diode conducting; your second equation applies (less a diode drop, but I assume from your use of a IGBT that you consider a diode drop to be negligible).
3. Switch open, diode not conducting; **in theory** the coil has neither current nor voltage (in practice it'll be ringing like a bell), and the cap voltage is only affected by the output current

Your challenge is that the time that the converter stays in the switch open, diode conducting state depends on the coil current when the switch opens -- the switch-over happens when the circuit wants it to, not from any external control.

Comment: Ok, so the third state is the reason of DCM. But how can i get to the equations mentioned in the Literature i provided?

Comment: That is somebody's *Bachelor's thesis*.  I wouldn't trust it very far at all.

Comment: yes, youre right. But there should be a mathematical decription for duc/dt and diL/dt if the converter runs in DCM?

Comment: What is \$di/dt\$ for an open-circuit inductor?  What is \$dv/dt\$ for a capacitor connected to a resistor?

Comment: **di/dt = 0** , **dv/dt = -1/RC** ?

Comment: I think you need to work on your circuit theory a bit more.  Take your schematic, erase the diode, show the switch as open, and then solve for the voltage on the cap, over time, as a function of an initial voltage.  Then **think**.